# After Update to 17.04 from 16.10 Enterprize Wifi connection with Proxy doesn't work

Tags: proxy, 17.04

I have an office Wifi where we have WPA2 Enterprize security with mschapv2 inner auth. We have a proxy for this network. It used to work fine till 16.10. After upgrade to 17.04, my laptop connects to this network successfully, but no sites open in any browser. The error message I see is Proxy not found. Ethernet and other wifi without proxy work fine, but for this office Wifi connection proxy seems to be not working.
I tried a number of solutions that I found here and there, but to no avail! Killing dnsmasq was one - but dnsmasq is not installed on my Ubuntu 17.04. Please let me know if there's anything else I can do.